# Проблема с Console.ReadKey в C#

Tags: c#, консоль

Всем привет. В общем такая проблема, при нажатии кнопки на клавиатуре происходят какие то действия

```
        Console.WriteLine("Здравствуйте");

        Repository repository = new Repository();
        repository.AddWorker(1, "Peter", "Junior", new DateTime(2020, 11, 09, 17, 27, 02));
        repository.AddWorker(2, "Ilya", "Middle", new DateTime(2020, 11, 09, 15, 21, 48));
        repository.AddWorker(3, "Dmitriy", "Senior", new DateTime(2020, 11, 09, 12, 11, 23));
        repository.GetAllWorkers();
        Console.WriteLine("");

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Введите 0 если хотите удалить определенного работника, или  1 чтобы добавить");

            if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.D0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Была нажата клавиша 0, напишите ID работника которого хотите удалить");
                string? input = Console.ReadLine();
                bool id = int.TryParse(input, out int inputId);

                repository.DeleteWorker(inputId);
                Console.WriteLine("");
                repository.GetAllWorkers();

                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("Желаете ли вы удалить из базы кого то еще?" +
                    "\nВведите 0 если да, и 1 если нет");
                if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.D0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    continue;
                }
                else if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.D1)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.D1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Была нажата клавиша 1, напишите всю требуемую информацию о работнике которого хотите добавить," +
                    $"\nа именно его ID, имя и должность");
                Console.WriteLine("");

                Console.Write("ID: ");
                string? inputId = Console.ReadLine();
                bool id = int.TryParse(inputId, out int intId);
                Console.WriteLine("");

                Console.Write("Имя: ");
                string? inputName = Console.ReadLine();
                string name = inputName ?? "Имя не указано";
                Console.WriteLine("");

                Console.Write("Желаемая должность: ");
                string? inputPosition = Console.ReadLine();
                string position = inputPosition ?? "Должность не указана";
                Console.WriteLine("");

                repository.AddWorker(intId, name, position, DateTime.Now);
                repository.GetAllWorkers();

                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("Желаете ли вы добавить в базу кого то еще?" +
                    "\nВведите 0 если да, и 1 если нет");
                if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.D0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    continue;
                }
                else if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.D1)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Была нажата какая то другая кнопка, попробуйте еще раз");
                continue;
            }
        }
```

Но почему то запрос нажатия кнопки выполняется два раза. То есть не текст приглашения ко вводу а именно в консоли мигает курсор. Что делать? Могу конечно поменять все на ReadLine и все будет работать прекрасно но хотелось бы чтоб пользователь не видел то что нажал

Comment: `var keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);` `if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.D0)` `if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.D1)` Опрашивать клавиатуру нужно один раз.

Comment: _0 если да, и 1 если нет_ - обычно 0 принимается за ложь/false/нет/no, а 1, соответственно, истина/true/да/yes.